# Javascript window.history.pushState is not detecting the browser refresh button

Tags: javascript, php, html, browser, pushstate

I am trying to refresh `window.history.pushState` url which refreshes the page with `F5` or `CTRL+5` but when i press the refresh button of browser it gives error.

`F5/CTRL+F5` or even browser refresh button will refresh the real url like `http://www.dddd.com/myrealpath/test/` but after `history.pushState` the `F5/CTRL+F5` refresh the `http://www.dddd.com/myrealpath/test/1/done/` with the state trick.

But browser refresh button does not refresh `http://www.dddd.com/myrealpath/test/1/done/`, it gives error of `Object not found!`.

Kind help is needed. Thanks

```
path = window.location.pathname;
  
window.history.pushState(null, null, path+"1/done/");

if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
    window.history.pushState(null, null, path+"1/done/");
}

$(document).on('keydown', function(event) {
    
    if (event.ctrlKey && (window.event.keyCode == 116)) {
        window.history.pushState(null, null, path);
    }
    if (window.event.keyCode == 116) {
        window.history.pushState(null, null, path);
    }
    
    if (event.ctrlKey && (event.keyCode == 123 || event.keyCode == 117)) { 
        window.history.pushState(null, null, path);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it by doing the below now browser refresh button is working also.

```
//master path - original path
path = window.location.pathname;

//Redirectss original path to this
window.history.pushState(null, null, path+"1/done/");

jQuery(window).bind("unload", function() { //
    window.location.href = path; // original path
});
```